# Switching bulbs? PAR20 halogen to PAR20 LED, is this a problem?

Tags: led, halogen

I have recessed lights that were sold as 'PAR20 halogen' use.  I see that there are PAR20 LED lights around, which would save some energy and last much longer than a halogen, and I was wondering if this was an ok thing to do?

When going back to the question/answer on the big orange website, the question had been asked and answered with an unequivocal no.

If you have the appropriate dimmer which is compatible with the bulb, what would be wrong with it?  Can't seem to find a good not to or any danger in it...

Comment: Are we talking low-voltage or line-voltage halogens here?

Comment: Line voltage halogen, the PAR20 bulb has an e26 base, the dimmer and bulbs I'd use are a match from the manufacturers list (Lutron) of compatibles.  Wires inside look like normal lighting wires in a line voltage fixture and without any kind of ballast that I can see, tho I think halogens work off of line voltage as-is?

Comment: the only issue would be compatibility with your dimmer.  Unfortunately some "dimmable" LEDs are "not really", or "you don't mind a little flicker do you?". My advice buy one and try it (at first try it alone with any other lights on the circuit removed)

Comment: good quality newer LED "bulbs" won't flicker when dimmed, even with standard dimmers. some halogens are 12-36v, some are AC; it depends on the filament, since resistive loads can happily accept AC or DC...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely should if you are able to line up an LED light and dimmer that play well together.  Incandescent is like neon: There is no earthly reason to invest in it for anything, unless you are doing something really specialty and cool.

As always, the big-box stores are an endless fount of bad advice.